# Does sending a character pointer - initialized to '\0' - to the standard output fault it? (C++)

Tags: c++, c++11

This is trivial, probably silly, but I need to understand what state *cout* is left in after you try to print the contents of a character pointer initialized to '\0' (or 0). Take a look at the following snippet:

```
const char* str;
str = 0; // or str = '\0';
cout << str << endl;
cout << "Welcome" << endl;
```

On the code snippet above, line 4 wont print "Welcome" to the console after the attempt to print **str** on line 3. Is there some behavior I should be aware of? If I substitute line 1-3 with **cout << '\0' << endl;** the message "Welcome" on the following line will be successfully printed to the console.

NOTE: Line 4 just silently fails to print. No warning or error message or anything (at least not using MinGW(g++) compiler). It spewed an exception when I compiled the same code using MS cl compiler.

EDIT: To dispel the notion that the code fails only when you assign **str** to '\0', I modified the code to assign to 0 - which was previously commented

Comment: @BoBTFish Its not so much about the intention here. The question I asked is whether (or how) it faults the standard output such that after that attempt, subsequent use of cout wont do what you'd expect. What I have up here is just a snippet. Long story is that I was consuming a library, a certain function was meant to return an initialized string but was not (a bug obviously). So my worry had more to do with the state that the action of printing a null pointer leaves the standard output, since it affects even my own code that I would have expected to work

Comment: Your code is just wrong. You mixed char and pointer to char.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you insert a `const char*` value to a standard stream (`basic_ostream<>`), it is *required* that it not be null. Since `str` is null you violate this requirement and the behavior is undefined.

The relevant paragraph in the standard is at §27.7.3.6.4/3.

The reason it works with `'\0'` directly is because `'\0'` is a `char`, so no requirements are broken. However, Potatoswatter has convinced me that [printing this character out is effectively implementation-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9920686/87234), so what you see might not quite be what you want (that is, perform your own checks!).

Comment: Bah, didn't see he was casting a character to a pointer! However, I don't think it's correct to say printing `'\0'` is safe; see my deleted answer.

Comment: @Potatoswatter There's nothing wrong with printing `'\0'`, as far as C++ is concerned.  Some output devices may react particularly to it, but this is true for just about any character.

Comment: @JamesKanze True about any *control* character, which is why they are allowed to have an unknown effect on the stream written to.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I'd say true about any character.  There are certainly devices which do something special when they receive the character `'a'`.  For that matter, what a device does with a character may depend on what came before, e.g. if it is part of an escape sequence.  The most one can say is that there is an intended meaning for the characters in the basic character set, along with a few control characters like `'\t'` or `'\n'`.  (Actually, `'\n'` is probably the most clearly defined.)

Comment: There's of course `isprint(char)`, and AFAICT POSIX specifies that `isprint('\0')` must be false but C doesn't.

Comment: @JamesKanze See my answer — text streams such as `cout` are only defined to preserve printing characters and certain whitespace. C only defines what happens when you re-read the written sequence, not special behavior about when it goes to a device. But `cin` and `cout` can go to another program through pipes, so it's relevant.

Comment: @Potatoswatter OK.  I see what you're saying---if `cout` goes to a file, you're only guaranteed to be able to read back the printables plus some whitespace (and `'\a'`?).  I'm not sure that's right (since what is printable depends on the locale), but it's possible, and `'\0'` can certainly behave specially.  Whereas I was talking about the output in general: send it to a device (printer, terminal, or who knows what), and the standard doesn't (and can't) say what might happen.

Comment: @Potatoswatter And it's an interesting question as to what it means to send output to a device.  As you point out, the standard describes the semantics in terms of what you get when you read it back in---what happens if the device doesn't support reading it back in is up in the air.

Answer (score 7):

Don't use `'\0'` when the value in question isn't a "character"
(terminator for a null terminated string or other).  That is, I think,
the source of your confusion.  Something like:

```
char const* str = "\0";
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

is fine, where `str` points to a string which contains a `'\0'` (in this
case, two `'\0'`).  Something like:

```
char const* str = NULL;
std::cout << str << std::endl;
```

is undefined behavior; anything can happen.

For historical reasons (dating back to C), `'\0'` and `0` will convert
implicitly to any pointer type, resulting in a null pointer.

Answer (score 3):

Just regarding the `cout << '\0'` part…

"Terminating the string" of a file or stream in text mode has an undefined effect on its contents. The C++ standard defers to the C standard on matters of text semantics (C++11 27.9.1.1/2), and C is pretty draconian (C99 §7.19.2/2):

> Data read in from a text stream will necessarily compare equal to the data that were earlier written out to that stream only if: the data consist only of printing characters and the control characters horizontal tab and new-line; no new-line character is immediately preceded by space characters; and the last character is a new-line character.

Since `'\0'` is a control character and `cout` is a text stream, the resulting output may not read as you wrote it.

Answer (score 3):

A `char*` that *points to* a null character is simply a zero-length string.  No harm in printing that.

But a `char*` whose value *is null* is a different story.  Trying to print that would mean dereferencing a null pointer, which is undefined behavior.  A crash is likely.

Assigning `'\0'` to a pointer isn't really correct, by the way, even if it happens to work:  you're assigning a character value to a pointer variable.  Use `0` or `NULL`, or `nullptr` in C++11, when assigning to a pointer.

Comment: I mentioned also that you get the same behavior if you do **str = 0** so am not really sure if what you propose would work

Comment: The "behavior" that you get is undefined behavior; you're asking `cout`'s `operator<<` to dereference a null pointer.  I'm not surprised that line 4 doesn't work, because you're putting your program into a broken state with line 3.

Comment: You're confusing yourself by doing `str = '\0'` because that null *character* gets implicitly cast to a null *pointer*, and when you do `cout << str` you're invoking the `operator<<` that prints *strings*, not *single characters*.  When you do `cout << '\0'` you're invoking the one that prints single characters, which is a completely different function that doesn't involve dereferencing any pointers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example:
http://ideone.com/8MHGH

The main problem you have is that str is pointer to a char not a char, so you should assign it to a string: `str = "\0";`

When you assign it to char, it remains 0 and then the fail bit of cout becomes true and you can no longer print to it. Here is another example where this is fixed:
http://ideone.com/c4LPh